# show/hide div on mouseover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, delegates

I have the following code and i want when the user moves the mouse over the div it will display and when the mouse moves out of div it will hide. Every thing seems ok but it is not working . can any one point out the mistake for me ??

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {


        $(document).delegate('#myDiv', 'mouseover', function () { mouse_OverDiv(); });
        $(document).delegate('#myDiv', 'mouseout', function () { mouse_OutDiv(); });
        function mouse_OverDiv() {

            $('#myDiv').css({ "visibility": "visible" });

        }
        function mouse_OutDiv() {

            $('#myDiv').css({ "visibility": "hidden" });

        }
    });

</script> 
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="myDiv" style="visibility:hidden">
this is my  div</div>

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invisible Elements can't trigger a mouseover event, because they have no width and height and therefore no place in the document to be hovered.

Maybe the css opacity can help you? Also see [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/rrvpu/).

Comment: @Ghokun: sure, the hover method is a shortcut these methods, the problem is only the css visibility.

Answer (score 2):

You're (were) missing `#`:

```
   ||
   vv
$('#myDiv').css({ "visibility": "visible" });
```

Btw, you can do this with just css using the `:hover` selector. Also `delegate()` is been replaced with `on()`. Finally, you don't need to create an anonymous function to call another function you can just do this:

```
    $(document).delegate('#myDiv', 'mouseover', mouse_OverDiv);

   // Notice there's no `()` invoking the function 
   // since you're using it as a reference.
```

**EDIT**

Try with this:

```
var $div = $('#myDiv'),
    hoverIn = function(){
        $div.css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    hoverOut = function(){
        $div.css('visibility', 'hidden');
    };

$('#myDiv').hover(hoverIn, hoverOut);
```

Comment: Mmm, don't know, seems like it should work. Try with `on()` or `hover()` instead. Btw, it's not a good idea to update your question with a proposed answer, it defeats the purpose of having answers, and it makes it hard for people to find the problem later on.

Comment: See edit, I added how to do it with `hover()`. Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

The `$('myDiv').css({ "visibility": "visible" });`

Should be

```
 $('#myDiv').css({ "visibility": "visible" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you hide the div you can't mouse over it again.
Check this sample

```
$(document).delegate('#myDiv', 'mouseover', function() {
    mouse_OverDiv();
});
$(document).delegate('#myDiv', 'mouseout', function() {
    mouse_OutDiv();
});

function mouse_OverDiv() {
    $('#myDiv').css({"color": "red"});
}

function mouse_OutDiv() {
    $('#myDiv').css({"color": "blue"});
}
```